# Not An Answer declined, text provided only an additional info

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

I think the answer 
[Merge multiple git repositories into one, keeping branches history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502970/merge-multiple-git-repositories-into-one-keeping-branches-history/26509120#26509120) does not try to answer the question at all, it just provides an additional tip, which may be useful when following other answers.

I have flagged this as NAA, flag was declined. I still think this is not an answer, hence this post - feel free to convince me (or just show your disagreement with me).

Comment: How do you know OP is advising and not attempting to provide a solution (a wrong one)? In this case, the answer should be downvoted while explaining that it's a wrong answer, but it still *an answer*.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Because he is not telling at all how to do the intended merge, only writes "before doing the merge, do something else, which is general usefull, but not relevant for this particular problem".

Comment: On the other hand, I can totally understand if your flag was actually accepted...

Comment: @Suma He may have thought doing that before the merge would fix the problem. Now that may be wrong, maybe blatantly so, but it can be seen as an attempt to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an attempt at an answer, albeit it may be a wrong one. For all intents and purposes, to someone who isn't knowledgeable in git (like some moderators) this looks like an (perhaps wrong, people can decide that by votes) attempt to answer the question.

It's worth noting that the NAA flag is only there for posts that *don't even attempt* to provide an answer to the question. The post here seems to do that, e.g. "Use $command before merge (implied: that will solve your problem)". Of course, that may not be the case, but that's for up and downvotes to decide.

There is an [excellent explaination by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) on what is an (attempted) answer and what isn't.